# Get unexpected keyword argument 'mimetype' when calling redirect in Flask

Tags: python, flask, http-headers

I have a REST API in python Flask which should post a string to a previously defined callback URL as the response. Here is my code:

```
return redirect(
    location=callback_url,
    code=200,
    Response=Response(status=200, response="Zeinab,Abbasimazar,1989,Sep,07")
)
```

But I got following error in console:

```
[2019-12-25 18:15:07,482] ERROR in app: Exception on /v1/PaymentPage [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zeinab/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/zeinab/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/zeinab/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/zeinab/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/zeinab/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/zeinab/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/zeinab/PycharmProjects/paygate_service_rest/server.py", line 323, in payment_page
    Response=Response(status=200, response=transaction.get_transaction_result_string(res_code=0))
  File "/home/zeinab/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/utils.py", line 506, in redirect
    mimetype="text/html",
TypeError: __call__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mimetype'
```

As I traced the code, this was set in library in file `python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/utils.py` in method `redirect`:

```
response = Response(
    '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">\n'
    "<title>Redirecting...</title>\n"
    "<h1>Redirecting...</h1>\n"
    "<p>You should be redirected automatically to target URL: "
    '<a href="%s">%s</a>.  If not click the link.'
    % (escape(location), display_location),
    code,
    mimetype="text/html",
)
```

I have changed my code to:

```
return redirect(
    location=callback_url,
    code=200,
    Response="Zeinab,Abbasimazar,1989,Sep,07"
)
```

And now I get:

```
[2019-12-25 18:26:01,109] ERROR in app: Exception on /v1/PaymentPage [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zeinab/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/zeinab/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/zeinab/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/zeinab/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/zeinab/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/zeinab/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/zeinab/PycharmProjects/paygate_service_rest/server.py", line 324, in payment_page
    Response=msg
  File "/home/zeinab/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/utils.py", line 506, in redirect
    mimetype="text/html",
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

How can I skip `mimetype` header or change it? Do I need any upgrades on my libraries?

Answer (score 0):

```py
return redirect(
    location=callback_url,
    code=200,
    Response=Response(status=200, response="Zeinab,Abbasimazar,1989,Sep,07")
)
```

The [only supported status codes](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.redirect) for `flask.redirect()` are 301, 302, 303, 305, 307, and 308. All HTTP redirects start with 3xx. I'm not sure of the exact cause of the specific exception, but this is likely the cause. If I had to guess, Flask does not expect a mimetype in a redirect request, because HTTP redirects (at least, the ones supported by Flask) do not have bodies, only headers. Try updating your code to this:

```py
return redirect(location=callback_url, code=302)
```

An HTTP status of 200 tells the browser that the request succeeded, and that it should render the content returned in the body. Some responses, like a 4xx response, can also have a body, because despite an error having occurred, the server may still be able to return HTML for the browser to render (like a custom 404 page). However, most 3xx codes are *not* allowed to have bodies, and are rather supposed to have a `Location` header which the browser will navigate to upon receiving the request. Content in the body will be ignored. A helpful list of HTTP status codes can be found [here](https://httpstatuses.com/).

With regards to the second half of your question, when you changed your code the second time, you replaced the `Response` parameter with the following:

```py
Response="Zeinab,Abbasimazar,1989,Sep,07"
```

What you had originally was correct (bar the response code); the `flask.redirect` method is looking for an object of type `Response` for the `Response` parameter (confusing, I know), but you're passing in an object of type `str`.

Hope this helps.

---

**TLDR: Change the `code` parameter of the `redirect` method to one of the supported redirect status codes and do not attempt to return a response body.**